How to do the scaling to remove bias in QP problem?
I have a MIQP problem as below
minimize $$\min {\bf x}^T{\bf Qx}-{\bf c}^T{\bf x}$$
${\bf x}$ is a binary variable. The range of values in ${\bf Q}$ and ${\bf x}$ are quite different. The elements of ${\bf Q}$ lies in the range of 0 and 1 while the values in ${\bf c}$ have mean around 20.
I want to put equal importance on both of these parameters. It seems from the result that ${\bf c}$ has quite strong influence. The results is more biased towards ${\bf c}$.
How do I scale one of these so that both ${\bf Q}$ and ${\bf c}$ have equal influence on the results, i.e., we remove the bias.
How I do it...
To balance the influence of the terms involving ${\bf Q}$ and ${\bf c}$ in your objective function, I scale one of them appropriately. Since the elements of ${\bf Q}$ are in the range of 0 and 1 while the values in ${\bf c}$ have a mean around 20, I scale ${\bf Q}$ to have a similar magnitude as ${\bf c}$. Here's how I can do it:
I compute the average value of ${\bf c}$, let's call it $\bar{c}$.
Then I compute the average value of the elements in ${\bf Q}$, let's call it $\bar{Q}$.
Then I scale ${\bf Q}$ by multiplying it by $\frac{\bar{c}}{\bar{Q}}$.
$$\min {\mathbf{x}}^T \left(\frac{\bar{c}}{\bar{Q}} \mathbf{Q}\right)\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x}
$$
Am I doing it right?

Is Q positive semi-definite?

@ErlingMOSEK unfortunately not

If $x$ is binary vector, you have $x^T D x = d^T x$ for any diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal $d$. This has two important consequences:

You can assume Q to be convex without loss of generality. In particular, given nonconvex $Q$, let $Q = H D H^T$ be its eigendecomposition and let $D^+ = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda > 0$ be a scaled identity matrix such that $D_{ii} + D^+_{ii} \geq 0$. Then $H (D + D^+) H^T = Q + D^+$ is positive semidefinite. Moreover, minimizing $x^T Q x - c^T x$ is the same a minimizing $x^T (Q + D^+) x - (d^+ + c)^T x$, where $d^+ = \lambda \mathbf{1}$ is the diagonal entries of $D^+$.

To balance the scaling of $x^T Q x$ and $c^T x$, note that the former can be rewritten as $x^T Q x = (Hx)^T D (Hx)$ for the eigendecomposition $Q = H D H^T$, and the latter is just $x^T C x$ where $C$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal $c$. The scaling of $x$ and $Hx$ are in balance, as on is just an orthogonal transformation of the other, so you just need to balance $D$ and $C$, that is, the eigenvalues of $Q$ and $c$. This can be done by scaling $c$ such that the norm of $c$ matches the norm of eigenvalues of Q. You may want to experiment with the one-norm, two-norm and infinity-norm to find what suit your needs the best.



... that is, the eigenvalues of $Q$ and $c$. Will it be $C$ in stead of $c$ here?

The eigenvalues of $C$ is the vector $c$. So you are right, but the text is also not wrong.
